# How to read from /dev/stdin with asyncio.create_subprocess_exec()

Tags: python, subprocess, python-asyncio

## Backround

I am calling an executable from Python and need to pass a variable to the executable. The executable however expects a file and does not read from stdin.

I circumvented that problem previously when using the subprocess module by simply calling the executable to read from `/dev/stdin` along the lines of:

```py
# with executable 'foo'
cmd = ['foo', '/dev/stdin']
input_variable = 'bar'

with subprocess.Popen(
    cmd,
    stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
    ) as process:
    stdout, stderr = process.communicate(input_variable)

    print(f"{process.returncode}, {stdout}, {stderr}")
```

This worked fine so far.
In order to add concurrency, I am now implementing asyncio and as such need to replace the subprocess module with the asyncio subprocess module.

## Problem

Calling asyncio subprocess for a program using `/dev/stdin` fails. Using the following async function:

```py
import asyncio

async def invoke_subprocess(cmd, args, input_variable):
    process = await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec(
        cmd,
        args,
        stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE,
        stdin=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE,
    )

    stdout, stderr = await process.communicate(input=bytes(input_variable, 'utf-8'))

    print(f"{process.returncode}, {stdout.decode()}, {stderr.decode()}")
```

This generally works for files, but fails for `/dev/stdin`:

```py
# 'cat' can be used for 'foo' to test the behavior
asyncio.run(invoke_subprocess('foo', '/path/to/file/containing/bar', 'not used')) # works
asyncio.run(invoke_subprocess('foo', '/dev/stdin', 'bar')) # fails with "No such device or address"
```

How can I call *asyncio.create_subprocess_exec* on `/dev/stdin`?

***Note***: I have already tried and failed via asyncio.create_subprocess_shell and writing a temporary file is not an option as the file system is readonly.

### Minimal example using 'cat'

Script `main.py`:

```py
import subprocess
import asyncio

def invoke_subprocess(cmd, arg, input_variable):
    with subprocess.Popen(
        [cmd, arg],
        stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
        ) as process:
        stdout, stderr = process.communicate(input_variable)

        print(f"{process.returncode}, {stdout}, {stderr}")


async def invoke_async_subprocess(cmd, arg, input_variable):
    process = await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec(
        cmd,
        arg,
        stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE,
        stdin=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE,
    )

    stdout, stderr = await process.communicate(input=input_variable)

    print(f"{process.returncode}, {stdout.decode()}, {stderr.decode()}")


cmd = 'cat'
arg = '/dev/stdin'
input_variable = b'hello world'

# normal subprocess
invoke_subprocess(cmd, arg, input_variable)
asyncio.run(invoke_async_subprocess(cmd, arg, input_variable))
```

Returns:

```sh
> python3 main.py
0, b'hello world', b''
1, , cat: /dev/stdin: No such device or address
```

Tested on:

- Ubuntu 21.10, Python 3.9.7
- Linux Mint 20.2, Python 3.8.10
- Docker image: python:3-alpine

Comment: Are you sure you're running the exact same program in both cases? Whether the program can access `/dev/stdin` should bear no relation to how it was started.

Comment: @user4815162342 'foo' is the exact same program. I was also surprised and wondered whether asyncio.create_subprocess_exec somehow forbids accessing `/dev/stdin` or runs for some magical reason with different permissions

Comment: It doesn't. But you can run your program with `strace -f` to check how it is being executed and (hopefully) what goes wrong. The "no such device or address" error is unusual, to say the least.

Comment: Will do. Thanks for pointing me into that direction. However, the same problem occurs when using good old `cat` as a program as well which indicates that this may not be related to the program itself.

Comment: Sure, `strace -f` is primarily to check how asyncio is execing the program, especially when compared to what the regular subprocess module is doing. They are supposed to be doing the same thing.

Comment: BTW can you create a minimal example that reproduces the issue (with `cat`)? If so, please edit the question to include it. Also, please state whether this is reproducible on multiple machines, or just on a machine with a particular kind of setup. In either case, please specify the type and version of the operating system you're testing it on.

Comment: Good point. Added the info.

Comment: Thanks for providing a minimal example, I can indeed reproduce this on my machine! `strace` confirms that `cat` is invoked correctly but (in the asyncio case) gets `ENXIO` when opening `/dev/stdin`. It seems the result of an implementation detail of asyncio subprocess vs regular subprocess is interfering with this. To see the difference, change `cmd, arg` to something like `"ls", "-l", "/self/proc/fd/0"`. For subprocess you'll get something like `/proc/self/fd/0 -> pipe:[7344202]`, whereas for asyncio you'll get `/proc/self/fd/0 -> socket:[7339428]`.

Comment: So asyncio uses [`socket.socketpair()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/43c5c1369cb21f08a1dc1d63923c3586b883e3e8/Lib/asyncio/unix_events.py#L797) to communicate with the subprocess, whereas subprocess uses [a pipe](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/43c5c1369cb21f08a1dc1d63923c3586b883e3e8/Lib/subprocess.py#L1595). Asyncio claims that "not all platforms support selecting read events on the write end of a pipe", naming AIX in particular. This seemingly inoccuous change breaks re-opening of `/dev/stdin`, which works with a pipe, but doesn't work with a socket. Bummer.

Comment: I think this should be reported as a bug on bugs.python.org, but I wouldn't hold my breath as to when it will be fixed (if at all).

Comment: Note that this also means that programs which implement special treatment for the `-` filename (esp. GNU tools like `cat`) will be able to use stdin in this case. It will depend on the implementation of the OP's `foo` program whether that is a useful workaround or not.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough analysis. I will report it to asyncio and see whether that is picked up.

Comment: FYI https://bugs.python.org/issue46364 . Feel free to extend on my description

Comment: Related Python PR: https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/30596

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll briefly wrap up the question and summarize the outcome of the discussion.

**In short**: The problem is related to a bug in Python's asyncio library that has been [fixed by now](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/90522). It should no longer occur in upcoming versions.

**Bug Details**: In contrast to the Python [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) library, [`asyncio`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html) uses a [`socket.socketpair()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/43c5c1369cb21f08a1dc1d63923c3586b883e3e8/Lib/asyncio/unix_events.py#L797) and not a pipe to communicate with the subprocess.
This was introduced in order to [support the AIX platform](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/asyncio/unix_events.py#L804).
However, it breaks when re-opening `/dev/stdin` that doesn't work with a socket.
It was fixed by only using sockets on AIX platform.